# problema de com a validação em Java

Tags: jsf-2.2, model-validation

Estou implementando validationBean no meu projeto, e estou tendo dificuldade para validar um campo, mas aparentemente está tudo certo nas configurações que fiz no meu projeto como podem ver:

Pacote:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Vejam como está o campo na minha entidade:

```java
@NotNull
@Column(precision = 10, scale = 2, nullable = false)
private BigDecimal valorImovel;
```

E vejam como está na minha pagina:

```jsp
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/template/LayoutPadrao.xhtml"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <ui:define name="titulo">Novo produto</ui:define>

    <ui:define name="corpo">
        <h:form>

            <h1>Novo produto</h1>

            <p:messages autoUpdate="true" closable="true" />

            <p:toolbar style="margin-top: 20px">
                <p:toolbarGroup>
                    <p:button value="Novo" />
                    <p:commandButton value="Salvar" id="botaoSalvar" />
                </p:toolbarGroup>
                <p:toolbarGroup align="right">
                    <p:button value="Pesquisa" />
                </p:toolbarGroup>
            </p:toolbar>

            <p:panelGrid columns="2" id="painel"
                style="width: 100%; margin-top: 20px" columnClasses="rotulo, campo">
                <p:outputLabel value="Nome do Imóvel" for="imovel" />
                <p:inputText id="imovel" size="20" maxlength="20" />

                <p:outputLabel value="Descrição do Imóvel" for="descimovel" />
                <p:inputText id="descimovel" size="60" maxlength="80" />

                <p:outputLabel value="Categoria" for="categoria" />
                <p:selectOneMenu id="categoria">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione a categoria" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>

                <p:outputLabel value="Subcategoria" for="subCategoria" />
                <p:selectOneMenu id="subCategoria">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione a subcategoria" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>

                <p:outputLabel value="Valor unitário" for="valorUnitario" />
                <p:inputText id="valorUnitario" size="10" maxlength="10"
                    value="#{cadastroImovelBean.imovel.valorImovel}" />


            </p:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Esse é o pedaço do código que me interessar:

```jsp
<p:outputLabel value="Valor unitário" for="valorUnitario" />
<p:inputText id="valorUnitario" size="10" maxlength="10"
    value="#{cadastroImovelBean.imovel.valorImovel}" />
```

Por que será que não validou meu campo?

Comment: já tentou processar o campo? Tipo <p:ajax event="change" process="@this" /> no seu input.

Comment: essa informação não está muito clara para mim, se você quiser você pode postar como resposta, fica mais interessante porque você vai poder explanar sua resposta de uma forma mais clara.

Comment: Resumindo, quando você clica no botão Incluir ele salva os dados no banco sem validar?

Comment: desculpe, mesmo assim não entendi.

Comment: Você tem um botão salvar certo? quando você clica nele o campo não é validado? Pelo que vi seu botão salvar não está ligado a nenhum evento pra salvar os dados no banco.

Comment: a sugestão do #Rafael ajuda no sentido de validar somente um campo, sendo que, eu quero somente validar um campo para questão de teste, mas que na prática ele vai ter que validar todos os outros campos que estou criando, eu fiz um teste utilizando o servidor TomCat, e funcionou normalmente. O servidor que eu estava usando era o wildFly do Jboss, deve existir uma maneira de usar diferente, mas  não acredito que seja essa abordagem que foi mencionada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para fazer processar todos os campos de seu painel você precisa de um botão.

```
<p:commandButton value="Salvar" process="painel @this" update="painel"/>
```

Com isso ele processa seu painel e faz a validação.